# Why is functional programming good for DSL? (Is it?)

Tags: functional-programming, dsl

I have a feeling that the common perception, at least in the functional programming community, is that functional programming is good for creating a DSL. What makes it superior to OOP in this area?

Answer (score 3):

DSLs can be implemented as simple, pipelined compilers. Many FP languages are traditionally well equipped for this kind of things, with features such as algebraic data types and pattern matching being the most useful. These features have nothing to do with functional programming per se, but for historic reasons they are rarely present in the non-FP languages.

Things get even more interesting if you want to verify your compiler implementation. For this, the total functional languages (like Coq) are unmatched. There is no sane way of doing anything similar for an OO compiler implementation.

On the other hand, functional languages are not necessarily the best possible *target* for such a DSL compiler (or a *host* if it's a eDSL).

There is also a culture of implementing eDSLs as ad hoc interpreters on top of FP languages, although I find this approach the least appealing.